# How to dump GNU screen scrollback buffer while preserving ANSI control sequences?

Tags: gnu-screen, ansi-escape

In a screen session, its scrollback buffer can be saved to file by entering `^A:hardcopy -h /path/to/filename`. However, this strips all ANSI control sequences from the output.

I want something like `less -R` but for saving the scrollback buffer.

example script to produce coloured text:

```
#!/bin/bash
# both times, the word 'red' is printed in bright red text.
printf 'example \x1b[1;31mred\x1b[m output\n' |tee example.log
cat example.log
```

you can also view the file with `less -R example.log`

Answer (score 1):

When the terminal consumes ANSI sequences, it does not store them in memory verbatim, but instead converts to display attributes of the individual characters on screen. `hardcopy`, apparently, was not designed to output those attributes.

You might get what you need if you enable logging, however. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/238001/164038), for example.